# Generating a report on Power BI using Powershell

Tags: r, powershell, powerbi

So I have this script on Powershell which generates a csv that is used on a Power BI template. When it is done with the csv it is supposed to open the template and show a report with the data updated but I still need to refresh it by hand.

***Edit:*** Forget it. The template opens updated but I still don't know if I can generate the report with commands

I have thought about using a "refresh update" and upload the report to the Power BI server but I don't want it to be only avaliable online.

This is my script (very basic version since its long):

```
#lots of commands to make the csv

Invoke-Expression "file"
```

The commands generate a clean csv which can be used with a common import but in R they appear as empty fields - probably because idk how to use R properly.

Is there any way I can do what I want using this script without having to upload the report first?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody is going to answer me, I'll give my final solution which is pretty bad but I want to close this asap so if anyone's having the same problem they can find a fast temporal solution.

My script to make tests:

```
##This creates a table which is used on a Power BI template

$num=0
$numpro=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter number of products"
echo("Name,Amount,Price") > products.txt


DO {
$num=$num + 1
$product=Read-Host -Prompt "Name of the product: "
$amount=Read-Host -Prompt "Amount we have of the product: "
$price=Read-Host -Prompt "Price for each product unit: "
echo("$product,$amount,$price") >> products.txt
}while($numpro -gt $num)

import-csv products.txt -delimiter "," | Export-csv products.csv

##clean lines
cat products.csv | where { $_ -match "#"} > delete.txt
$erase=Get-Content delete.txt
cat products.csv | %{$_ -replace "$erase",""} > def.txt
GC def.txt | where{$_ -ne ""} > products.csv

rm products.txt
rm delete.txt
rm def.txt

Invoke-Expression "full path to our .pbit"
```

Just use the script a first time without using "Invoke-Expression" to create a first table that you will use to create the template.
After creating the template, just use it full.

Btw: You **have to use absolute paths** on Power BI so don't change the file that contains the table and, if you do that, **be sure to change the source and save the template again**.